# Databricks DBX named parameters through job

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-dbx

I am trying to implement this(where I don't have variables in the conf file but passed it as named arguments)

[image: parameterpassing]

mentioned [here](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/cli/).

When running in local mode and a python debugger, I can easily pass this as:

```
Fundingsobj = SomeClass(init_conf={"localmode": "true", "fundingsdatapath": "tmp/fundings"})
Fundingsobj.launch()
```

where `SomeClass` inherits `Task`

However, I can't seem to pass this through the deployment.yaml. I have tried many versions

[image: attemmpt 1]

[image: attempt 2]

[image: Attempt 3]

[image: Attempt 4]

This is how I tried to read

```
class SomeClass(Task):
    """Class containing methods for generating test data."""

    def initialize(self):
        """Initialize method."""
        self.localmode = self.conf["localmode"]
```

This works fine, if I use the normal --conf-file option in the `deployment.yaml` and then provide the values there, or use the init_conf when I use the local debugger.

How do I pass variables to the job without relying on a conf file?

Idea is, after the job is deployed in Databricks, I would like to schedule it from Airflow by passing variables everyday.

Error while launching the job -

[image]

EDIT 1:
I have tried to use kwargs, but even that gives me the same error:

```
named_parameters:  {"localmode": "true","fundingsdatapath": "tmp/fundings"}
```

and then try to consume, using

```
def initialize(self, **kwargs):
        """Initialize method."""
        self.localmode = kwargs["localmode"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Basically, one has to use `argparse` for this.

So, after I defined my yaml to be (in deployment.yaml)

```
      - name: "clientscoretestdatageneratorusingparams"
        tasks:
          - task_key: "loadtestdataparams"
            <<:
              - *basic-static-cluster
            libraries:
              - pypi:
                  package: someadditionalpkg
                  repo: http://internalartifactoryurl
            python_wheel_task:
              package_name: "workflows"
              entry_point: clientscoretestdatagenerator
              named_parameters: {"localmode": "true","fundingsdatapath": "tmp/fundings"}
```

then in the entrypoint method

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
....class and its other methods.....
....................................
def entrypoint():  # pragma: no cover
    """Entrypoint for spark wheel jobs."""
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--localmode", dest="localmode", default=False)
    parser.add_argument("--fundingsdatapath", dest="fundingsdatapath", default="tmp/fundings")
    parser.add_argument("--datalakename", dest="datalakename", default="datalakename")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    fundingsobj = GenerateClientScoreData()
    fundingsobj.launch(args)
```

and then consume using

```
   def initialize(self, args):
       """Initialize method."""
       self.localmode = args.localmode
```

Comment: This makes sense and worked for me as well. However, I didn't see `named_parameters` mentioned anywhere in dbx's docs, could you link to where this you found this?

Comment: Hey, I had the link in my question itself. Look for the hyperlink right after the first screenshot.

Comment: Completely missed that, thank you!