# databricks bundle wheel job add Parameters

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-asset-bundle

Here is an example resources yaml i am using with asset bundle:

```yaml
 name: "clientscoretestdatageneratorusingparams"
        tasks:
           task_key: "mytask
            python_wheel_task:
              package_name: "workflows"
              entry_point: clientscoretestdatagenerator
```

I want to add a parameter to this so that I can access it using `sys.arg[1]`.

I have both tried `named_parameters` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743917/databricks-dbx-named-parameters-through-job)) and just `parameters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have gone wrong with your syntax somewhere. The `parameters` field needs to be an array, so something like this should work:

```yaml
 name: "clientscoretestdatageneratorusingparams"
        tasks:
           task_key: "mytask
            python_wheel_task:
              package_name: "workflows"
              entry_point: clientscoretestdatagenerator
              parameters: ["string1", "string2"]
```

Also make sure its indentation is correct. It should be 1 indentation level deeper than your `python_wheel_task`.

Comment: it was the spacing, I hate yaml